# Converting Timezone of object in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to change a UTC time that is in my Postgresql database to an Eastern Time to send in a mailer. I have been going crazy trying to convert these and just can't seem to get it right.

Time is was actually created (EST): 1:33pm
Calls in console:

```
item.created_at => "2015-09-07 17:33:16"
item.to_time("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") => 2015-09-07 17:33:16 +0000
item.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").to_time.strftime("%l:%M%p") => 9:33PM
```

It seems like there is some type of conversion going on (going from 17:33 to 21:33) but it is 'backwards'? It should go down 4 hours not up 4 hours.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: you should try this `item.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M%p")` i think `to_time` is converting it back to `utc`

Comment: It looks like that just sends back the original time just formatted => 5:33PM

Is there a way to set the to_time method to another timezone than utc?

Comment: what should be your expected output time. ?

Comment: 1:33PM is what i want it to be.

Comment: i used `time = "2015-09-07 17:33:16"` and then i see the time in your time zone like this `Time.parse(time).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")` it returned this `Mon, 07 Sep 2015 08:33:16 EDT -04:00` you see it is having `8:33` in it,  now when i tried to see using strftime(which is used to get only required format), it gives => `" 8:33AM"` im sorry but im not sure how are you expecting time to be `1:33PM`

Comment: i physically created the object at 1:33PM on my local machine. Since the data is stored in UDT in the DB, i assumed i could apply the in_time_zone method to it to get it back to my local time. I guess I'm going to have to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

You only need this:

```
item.created_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
```

Here's a contrived example:

```
[2] pry(main)> time = Time.now.utc
=> 2015-09-07 17:51:17 UTC
[3] pry(main)> time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
=> Mon, 07 Sep 2015 13:51:17 EDT -04:00
```

Comment: Anthony, It works if I make a new item in rails console, however not on an existing item in the database. 

  `item.created_at => 2015-09-07 17:33:16.908491`
  `item.created_at.in_timezone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)" ) => 2015-09-07 17:33:16 -0400`

It seems to show the -04:00, but not actually take it from the time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but there's an option in application.rb to set your timezone. Kindly check

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, this was my mistake.

Since the information I was getting was from a query, I for some reason had to parse the created_at to a DateTime object before I was able to use the in_time_zone method.

So, in the end,

`DateTime.parse(time).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")`

worked just as it should have.